# Rust - Wrapping User provided Safe Function into Unsafe FFI Function for FFI Callback

Tags: function, rust, closures, ffi

I'm trying to wrap a unsafe FFI function into a "safer" Function.
At the moment, my problem basically looks like this:

```
fn do_ffi_safe(arg1: u16, callback: fn(result: u16) -> bool) {
    //I have to wrap callback into a unsafe extern "C" fn here to use as a callback

    do_ffi_unsafe(arg1: u16, Some(//And use the unsafe callback here));
}

unsafe extern "C" do_ffi_unsafe(arg1: u16, Option<unsafe extern "C" fn(result: u16) -> bool);
```

How can i wrap the safe function into a (probably anonymous) function inside the function body?

Can i use Closures? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap unsafe code in a safe function. There is, in fact [a section in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#creating-a-safe-abstraction-over-unsafe-code) that tells you exactly how.

The below is an example copied from the book, restated for brevity:

```
use std::slice;

fn split_at_mut(slice: &mut [i32], mid: usize) -> (&mut [i32], &mut [i32]) {
    let len = slice.len();
    let ptr = slice.as_mut_ptr();

    assert!(mid <= len);

    unsafe {
        (slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, mid),
         slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr.offset(mid as isize), len - mid))
    }
}
```

For future reference, the Rust team provides what I'd guess is some of the best documentation in the industry to answer questions like these. I can't stress enough that newcomers should use it to its fullest extent; it's a rare and incredibly useful gem.

Comment: I need the exact opposite though, I have to pass a unsafe function through the ffi, but I want the user of my library to have to pass a safe function, so I have to wrap a safe function in a unsafe one. (I guess the bigger problem is that this has to happen at runtime)

Comment: You can also call the user's safe function from an unsafe one that you defined (sorry for late response).